# Load data from an existing View to table in Snowflake and shcedule it to run everyday - incremental

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm new to snowflake and I have to Load data from an existing View to table in Snowflake and also, need to shcedule it to run everyday - incremental.

How to achieve it in snowflake.Suggestions required.

Comment: If you need incremental, you should look at using streams https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html. However, streams work on tables not views. You'll need to put one on each table that builds the view and run your DML statements off a SQL statement matching the view definition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

- create a Stored Proc that inserts/merges into the table from the view, implementing whatever business logic you need to apply
- create a task that runs the SP
- add a schedule to the task